# Modifier keys behaviour on hyperlink clicks

Tags: html, web, w3c, web-standards

Is there some standards for hyperlink click behaviour with a modifier key pressed?
For example, firefox creates a new tab if `Ctrl` is pressed and creates a new window if `Shift` is pressed.
Opera creates new unfocused tab on `Ctrl`, and focused - on `Shift`.
Is it totally browser dependent or there are some guidelines, that should be considered?

Answer (score 1):

This is browser-dependent, and is much more complex than you seem to expect: there's also middle-click (which does not fire an `onclick`), there are Apple keyboards where it's Command+click (not Ctrl+click), "Open Link in a New Tab" context menu, mobile browsers, and many more.

You say [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976325/modifier-keys-behaviour-on-hyperlink-clicks#comment21029845_14976399):

> I'm writing a js for my website, and i want to know, what behaviour user expects, clicking on a hyperlinks with binded onClick events.

The suggested way is to provide an actual URL in the `href` element if possible and let the browser handle opening it in a new tab. You can override the default behaviour for a simple left-click by cancelling the event from the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the

```
target="_blank"
```

attribute to force the webpage to open in a new tab/window (depending on the browser). For example:

```
<a href="www.google.com" taget="_blank">
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Well I done a bit of looking into it and can't see anything regarding hyperlinks and modifiers, the only think i can think of is dealing with the modifier key in the javascript.

If its an issue having new pages pop up in new tabs/windows you could do something like the following to disable it. However if the user disables javascript then the link wont work at all which isn't ideal.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Event Modifiers</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function checkMods(event){
       if(event.shiftKey) {
        alert("Shift, held.");
        return false
       }
       else{
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
        return true
       }

}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Event Modifiers</H1>
<HR>
<P>This link wont work if Shift is held while clicking. 
<A HREF="javascript:void(0)" onClick="return checkMods(event)">
this link</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I know, this is not what i was asking about.

Comment: My bad, eh as far as i am aware it would be browser dependent. Is there a particular reason you are asking as I have never known it to be an issue for users.

Comment: I'm writing a js for my website, and i want to know, what behaviour user expects, clicking on a hyperlinks with binded onClick events.